# An authentication server in Asia Pacific is refusing access to some of my Fusion Tables Android App users

Tags: google-fusion-tables

My Geo based Android app uses Fusion Tables accessed via oAuth to store route information for users.

For the last couple of years I sporadically get notifications from users in Asia Pacific telling them that their authentication has failed.  This means that the key that is registered on the API dashboard for com.spiralsoftware.bestroutepro is not being recognized.

This does not happen for all users in that region and has not happened anywhere else in the world.  I suspect that there must be a bad server somewhere that my users connect to sometimes.

Once the authentication has failed it doesn't seem to come back: they appear to be locked out of being able to load their saved routes forever.

Normally the users experiencing the problem are in Australia or New Zealand but this evening I received an email from a user in the Philippines.

I can't create another API key without deleting the existing one which means all other users will be unable to access their Fusion Tables until they upgrade the app.

The folks who are affected have paid money for the app and I don't know what to tell them.

Is there anything I can do to get these users authenticated?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How do I get a valid oAuth token for a user when the Authentication server will not give them one?

Comment: Maybe it's no good idea to sell software which is based on a experimental API(that's what FusionTables are)

Comment: Fusion Tables graduated from Google Labs back in September 2009 and the current terms of service for the API seem the same as most of the other Google APIs.  I'm not worried that they label it experimental.  I don't even believe my problem is directly with Fusion Tables itself: just the access to it for some of my users.